Parallax effect on iphone
I have a little problem with a parallax effect on my site. When I open it with iphone I don't see the photos on background. Here is the CSS code:
.parallax-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 450px; /* Height of the parallax section */
    overflow: hidden;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}

.background-image-1 {
    background-image: url('image.jpg');
}

and the HTML structure:
<div class="parallax-container background-image-1">
            <section class="parallax-section"></section>
        </div>

        <section class="content-section">
            /*TEXT HERE*/
        </section>
        
        <div class="parallax-container background-image-2">
            <section class="parallax-section"></section>
        </div>

Here is the page where there is the problem:
https://www.beachvolleyinstitute.it/index.php
Anyone can help me?
Removing background-repeat: no-repeat; I can see the images, but not in the correct way. There are repeating and not correctly positioned.

I forgot to post the content-section class CSS. Here it is:
.content-section {
background-color: transparent;
color: black;
padding: 20px;
/height: 450px;/ /* Height of the content area */
box-sizing: border-box;
text-align: center;
font-family:'Carrois Gothic';
}
